# Angular (4) routing appends components to one page instead of destroying a component first. I am hosting an Angular (4) application on heroku

Tags: angular, heroku

EDIT - so I just took out flatMap and performed a conventional get request. Works now I guess.

My -show component seems to break my application's routing. When I try and use a routerLink after viewing one of my show pages, all subsequent routing appends the views to the current page. It seems ngOnDestroy stops firing after visiting a show page?

This is what I see in the inspector:

```
<app-root>
  <nav></nav>
  <home-page></home-page>
  <graphic-show></graphic-show>
  <graphics></graphics>
</app-root>
```

And this is what I what I want to happen

```
<app-root>                      <app-root>
  <nav></nav>                     <nav></nav>
  <home-page></home-page> ===>    <another-selector></another-selector>
</app-root>                     </app-root>
```

When I don't visit a show page, only one component is rendered at a time. Visiting any show page (direct url or via routerLink from graphics component) makes all subsequent components append to the top of the page like this.

this is my show component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Graphic } from './graphic';
import { GraphicService } from './graphic.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'graphic-show',
  templateUrl: 'graphic-show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['graphics.component.css'],
  providers: [GraphicService]
})

export class GraphicShowComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private graphicService: GraphicService,
    private http: Http
  ){}

  @Input()
  graphic: Graphic;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    let graphicRequest = this.route.params
        .flatMap((params: Params)=>
          this.graphicService.getGraphic(+params['id']));
          graphicRequest.subscribe(response => this.graphic = response.json());
  }     
}
```

here is my service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Graphic } from './graphic';

@Injectable()
export class GraphicService {
  private graphicsUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobwoographics.herokuapp.com/graphics';

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ){}

  getGraphics(): Observable<Graphic[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.graphicsUrl)
                    .map((response: Response) => <Graphic[]>response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getGraphicsCarousel(){
    return this.http.get(this.graphicsUrl+"/carousel")
                    .map((response: Response) => <Graphic[]>response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getGraphic(id: number){
    return this.http.get(this.graphicsUrl+"/"+id+".json");
  }

  createGraphic(graphic) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.graphicsUrl, JSON.stringify(graphic), {
      headers: headers
      }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message :error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

app.module has my router setup

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';
import { NgUploaderModule } from 'ngx-uploader';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BusyModule } from 'angular2-busy';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { GraphicsComponent } from './graphics/graphics.component';
import { GraphicsCarouselComponent } from './graphics/graphics-carousel.component';
import { GraphicShowComponent } from './graphics/graphic-show.component';
import { GraphicsNewComponent } from './graphics/graphics-new.component';
import { GraphicService } from './graphics/graphic.service';
import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts/contacts.component';
import { ContactsNewComponent } from './contacts/contacts-new.component';
import { ContactService } from './contacts/contact.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent},
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent},
  { path: 'graphics', component: GraphicsComponent },
  { path: 'graphic/:id', component: GraphicShowComponent},
  { path: 'graphics/new', component: GraphicsNewComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'contacts/new', component: ContactsNewComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomepageComponent,
    GraphicsComponent,
    GraphicsCarouselComponent,
    GraphicShowComponent,
    GraphicsNewComponent,
    ContactsComponent,
    ContactsNewComponent,
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BusyModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    ),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    CarouselModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    NgUploaderModule
  ],
  providers: [
    Angular2TokenService,
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    GraphicService,
    ContactService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Either add your routing code (at the very least) or reproduce the problem in a plunkr and add the link to your question.

Comment: Sorry I added a bit more context. Let me know if there is anything else I can add.

Comment: Please also add your `Routes` setup and `RouterModule` initialisation in the parent Module(s)

Comment: I couldn't find a routerLink or router.navigate in your code. I guess what you're missing is to prefix the routes path with `../` if you want to route to a sibling route, or `/` to indicate that the route path is a full (absolute) path.